# what are the best practices for incorporating ngx-boostrap in your project

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

Good Morning ,

I am keen to know , how are you incoporating ngx-bootstrap modules in your project . what are the recommended and best practices.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in the [official documentation](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap#installation-instructions), you need to import the module of the feature that you need to use inside your [angular module](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules#the-basic-ngmodule).

For example, let's assume that you need to use the [Datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker), you will import it doing:

```
import { BsDatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';


@NgModule({
  imports: [BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),...]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

then you will be able to use the DatePicker inside your module.

For example adding it to one of your component's template:

```
<input
  #dp="bsDatepicker"
  bsDatepicker
  [bsValue]="bsValue"
>
```

in this case you need to initialise `bsValue` inside your component's class:

```
 bsValue = new Date();
```

Comment: Thanks your answer . If you are using many components , how would you group them ?  Would you put them in a separate module and import that module in your feature modules ? I am looking at having a source of truth for all the components I use

Comment: I don't think it matters how many components you use, but it matters **where** you use them. If you use them across all your application, then it makes sense to import them in your root module. Otherwise, if you use a component X only in a module Y, then you should import X from Y and not from your root component.